# Selecting Positive/Negative Values of a computation SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a User model and a Workplace model. User has a field gender(m/f) and each workplace has many users. I want to select the count of total number of users in a workplace and also the count of total number of female users of a workplace all grouped by workplace name.

Here is what I tried.

```
User.select("workplaces.name as workplace_name, count(*) as FTE, (count(case when   users.gender='m' and users.created_at BETWEEN date_trunc('month', now()) and now() then 1   end)::float - count(case when users.gender='f' and users.created_at BETWEEN   date_trunc('month', now()) and now() then 1 else null end)::float)/100 as ratio").joins("INNER   JOIN workplaces on workplaces.id=users.workplace_id").group(:workplace_name).order("ratio    desc").limit(5).map(&:attributes)
```

The above query gets the male and female users in a workplace and calculates (females - males)/100 as such.
I get ratio as both positive and negative values.

How do I select only positive values/negative values of ratio calculated

Thanks

Comment: As of now I am getting both positive and negative values from ratio calculated. How to select only positive ratio values ?

Comment: As in [`ABS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs)?

Comment: `HAVING`? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING

Comment: @pozs Having can be used. But ratio is not a field/column on the table. So how to use it ? having("ratio > 0") does not work

Comment: There _isn't_ such a thing as a [negative ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio).  There's also no reason to divide a ratio by 100.  If you want a _ratio_, it'd be `female/male`.  If you want a _percentage_, it's `female/totalEmployees`.  Which do you want?  It looks close to percentage difference, but isn't right for that either.

Comment: Also, depending on the type of `created_At` [you don't want to be using `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (remember that MySQL can declare varying fractional seconds).  You are aware your `FTE` count will return a different result than your male/female counts, right?  Due to the extra conditions in the `CASE` - you probably need to move those to the `WHERE` clause or `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING` clause here, as it accepts any expression, not just columns, like:

```
HAVING (expr_for_ratio) > 0
```

[<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b73c3/9)

Also, you could use a subquery here, but that would be complicated to write down in rails' api.